# Capacitor vs battery which cost less per capacity?

Tags: batteries, capacitor, energy

I know that batteries have better density ie capacity per volume.

But I want to get the most energy capacity for the money. Which one would would you get?

I'm trying to store energy from solar for 1 day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that the traditional Lead-Acid battery will be the best choice for this application at this moment.

Have a look here: [allaboutbatteries.com](http://www.allaboutbatteries.com/Battery-Energy.html)
Scroll down a bit to the green table and notice that indeed Lead-Acid
batteries have the lowest Cost per stored WattHour.

In the coming years this might shift to Li-ion based batteries as these improve in cost and performance (there is less development in the Lead-Acid department I believe). Li-Ion batteries are more difficult to use than Lead-Acid batteries though. Lead-Acid batteries are more robust in general.

Answer (score 1):

Batteries, by a long way. Exactly which sort depends on how big a system and what you have available, but both lead-acid and li-ion/li-poly are widely used for this purpose. Some larger systems use NiFe which has a longer lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Batteries have much better $/Joule initial investment costs. However, the overall cost should also be considered. Ultracapacitors have much longer lifetimes, and may survive better in outdoor environments. Once you account for maintenance and replacement costs, ultracaps *can* be more cost-effective.

In short, it depends on the details of your application.